# Train NN or SVM to classify stock signals

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am applying Neural network and SVM to predict buy-hold - sell signals. I have trained nn and SVM in R. I used nnet function to train NN and svm to train SVM. I provided 20,000 data points to train and 2000 data points to test. training data set contain list of 10-15 technical indciators and buy-sell-hold signals. The problem I am having is it is not predicting the buy -sell - hold signals with good accuracy on the testing data. I have used sigmoid function in nnet and radial function in SVM. Any suggestion, how to improve the accuracy of the prediction?

Comment: Use cross-validation or basically u need to find the best value of C and gamma to improve the accuracy of prediction. hope this helps...

Comment: I tried various values of C and gamma varying between (1-100) for C and (0.001 - 1) for gamma. Still no sucess.

Comment: sometimes the gamma values can go higher as well.. like 8...

Comment: look at this qn..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047459/retraining-after-cross-validation-with-libsvm it was posted by me... look at amro's ans...

Comment: or you could use the grid.py for grid search..

Comment: I am working in R and have been trying across range of values of C and Gamma. SVM trains acccurately and give 100% correct prediction on training data for high gamma but does not perform well for validation dataset. This looks overfitting problem to me. I don't know how to overcome this poverfitting issue? Is it really possible to overcome this overfitting issue by only changing the value of C and Gamma or Do I need to care for something else as well to get rid of overfitting?

Comment: is your values between 0 to 1 or -1 to 1?

Comment: how many fold validation did u do?

Comment: My target vector is but-sell-hold signals mean I have classification problem with 3 output classes. I have been using 10 fold testing and my best output comes as gamma = 0.2 and cost=10. When I train SVM with these optimal parameters, it gives good results on training and still fail to predict precisely on testing data

Comment: If you dont mind, You give me your email id and I will send you my data to train and you can experiment. That will be great help for me either.

Comment: SVM is for binary classification. If 3 classes, you need to multi-class svm...either one versus rest or one vs one...

Comment: libsvm supports one vs one...

Comment: Which package supports multiclass SVM in R? any idea?

Comment: not sure... try libsvm..add a tag called r to your question.. people expert in r may see it...

Comment: I have seen a small example in R SVM document, where SVM classifying data into 3 classes

Comment: sorry couldn't help you that much... maybe u want to read R SVM FAQ... sometimes, they might say the common mistakes possible..

Comment: Can anyone help me with regards to my original problem because the problem still persisst?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading ["A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification" by Chih-Wei Hsu, Chih-Chung Chang, and Chih-Jen Lin](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)

In the work I've done much lower values of C work better - in the range of $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-2}$. 1-100 is a pretty high value of C, at least for the data I've worked with, which means you are not allowing much 'slack' and so its not surprising that you are finding your model over-fits the data. I would recommend trying with much smaller values of C and in orders of magnitude increments.  Another alternative is to try nu-SVM rather than C-SVM. The parameter nu ranges from 0 to 1 (.1 to .8 in practice) and is much more intuitive: .1 means a small proportion of your data points are support vectors (and therefore you have a narrow margin and little slack), .8 means a very large percent are support vectors (and therefore a wide margin and a good deal of slack).

Answer (score 3):

Although not a direct answer to your question, are you sure that the 10-15 technical indicators you have chosen are the right ones or have the right look back periods etc? There are literally hundreds of indicators to chose from, and this combined with the choice of parameters gives you a "universe" of millions of different combinations of 10-15 indicators. Your problem might not be with the NN or SVM per se, but rather that your inputs are basically just random noise. Have you tested each of your chosen indicators separately and confirmed that they are statistically significant in any way? In my experience very few of the "standard" technical indicators pass any basic statistical or Monte Carlo test for significance, predictive ability etc.

Comment: Could you help me in identifying the right set of technical inicators. Even I was thinking there is some problem with the input indicators. Could you help me what criterion input technical indicator should follow?

Comment: My guess is that the "right" technical indicators are a well-guarded secret.  Perhaps you could select 10 different types of indicators, and give each one 10 different combinations of parameters, which will give you 100 total inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I have trained neural netowrk with 40-45 technical indicators but the problem comes as misclassification. My actual buy signals are predicted as sell signals and vice versa or hold signals are predicted as buy or sell signals and vice versa which does not help to devise a profitable strategy. I have tested across range of parameter buy no success. I am using combination of movig averages, RSI,MACD,BB,SMI,ADX,ret,sd,mean,return, cimullative return, CCI,CHV,Chaikain volatility, SAR and so on as input to the NN. Noise in the input indicatos causes hevoc.